# Unable to PUT a message to SQS Queue using cURL

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

We are trying to run the below cURL command from an EC2 instance which has IAM role with full permission for SQS and EC2.

```
curl -v https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2775421xxxxx/QueueName -d "Action=SendMessage&Version=2011-10-01&MessageBody=example"
```

**Error**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-10-01/">
   <Error>
      <Detail>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
        <Message>Access to the resource https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2775421xxxxx/QueueName is denied.</Message>
      <Detail/>
   </Error>
   <RequestId>01a5e8f1-d9df-5b72-a0d4-bb50bf23f04f</RequestId>
 </ErrorResponse>
```

Can you please help us.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using cURL you need to provide the `AccessKeyId` & `SecretAccessKey` for each request. Otherwise the request isn't signed and you get `AccessDenied` as a result.

Before doing it i recommend to use [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli), has the benefit that the EC2-Instance-Profile is used automatically in each call through the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli).

In your example it looks like this:

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2775421xxxxx/QueueName --message-body "example"
```